# How do I apply a python script that adds bullets points to lists in a notepad?

Tags: python

This is a dumb question, so when I searched the web I only found answers to more advanced problems.

**OK, so I made a script: bulletPointAdder.py**

**In a notepad I have a list (one item on each line).**

**How do I apply the script I made to the notepad file?**

(the script is working as intended because I'm using the "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python" by Al Stweigart - but the book isn't helping or I'm incapable of understanding)

```
#! python3
# bulletPointAdder.py - Adds Wikipedia bullet points to the start
# of each line of text on the clipboard.

import pyperclip
text = pyperclip.paste()

# Separate lines and add stars.
lines = text.split('\n')
    for i in range(len(lines)): # loop through all indexes in the "lines" list
        lines[i] = '* ' + lines[i] # add star to each string in "lines" list
text = '\n'.join(lines)
pyperclip.copy(text)
```

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: https://github.com/Pexan/luso/blob/master/bulletPointAdder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code you use a librairy "pyperclip" that will get the text in the clipboard (when you do a copy ctrl+insert) into a variable 'text'.

Then 'text' is splitted into a list of lines as '\n' means end of line.

Then *(error of indentation: the 'for' line should be at the indentation as previous lines)* the code takes each line indexed by i (as len(lines) is the length of the list 'lines') and add to each element i of the list 'lines' the string '* '

Now, out of the loop, the variable 'text' becomes a string that merges all new element of the list of lines 'lines'

Finaly, pyperclip.copy (so it calls for the function "copy" defined into the library "pyperclip) copies the string into the clipboard.

```
import pyperclip    # a librairy of function that allows you communicating with the clipboard
text = pyperclip.paste()  # takes the string from the clipboard

 and add stars.
lines = text.split('\n') # Separate the text into a list of lines
for i in range(len(lines)): # loop through all elements of the list in the "lines" list using the index 'i'
        lines[i] = '* ' + lines[i] # merges a star and a space behind the previous line of text. For each line i of 'lines', add '* '
text = '\n'.join(lines) # merges all elements of the list 'lines' into a string
pyperclip.copy(text) # export the string 'text' to the clipboard
```